# Server-Sent Events with Ruby Grape

Tags: javascript, ruby, server-sent-events, ruby-grape

I am trying to create Server-Sent events on my [Ruby Grape API](https://github.com/intridea/grape).
The problem is that the connection seems to be closed really fast all the time, as I get `Connection closed` event all the time on test webpage.

The client connects to the server as I can see the method being called, but I would like to know why is the connection not constant and why I don't receive the data I send using the Thread.

Here is my Ruby code:

```
$connections = []

class EventsAPI < Sinantra::Base

  def connections
    $connections
  end

  get "/" do
    content_type "text/event-stream"
    stream(:keep_open) { |out|
      puts "New connection"
      out << "data: {}\n\n"
      connections << out
    }
  end

  post "/" do
    data = "data\n\n"
    connections.each { |out| out << data }
    puts "sent\n"
  end

end
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
  var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:9292/events');

  source.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("New message: ", e.data);
      showMessage(e.data);
  };

  source.onopen = function(e) {
      // Connection was opened.
  };

  source.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Source Error", e)
      if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
          console.log("Connection was closed");
          // Connection was closed.
      }
  };

  var showMessage = function(msg) {
      var out = document.getElementById('stream');
      var d = document.createElement('div')
      var b = document.createElement('strong')
      var now = new Date;
      b.innerHTML = msg;
      d.innerHTML = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" +now.getSeconds() + "  ";
      d.appendChild(b);
      out.appendChild(d);
  };
```

EDIT: I got it working with the GET method (I changed the Grape::API to Sinatra::Base as Grape does not implement stream). I now receive data, but the connection is not kept alive and when I use the post method the data never reaches the browser.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I just answered, but if you are following an example specifically for SSE in the Grape API it would be useful to post a link to that documentation. (In particular I'm wondering what exactly `:keep_open` does.)

Answer (score 0):

The JS code looks correct. My guess is that you should not start a new thread for your infinite loop. What will be happening is that the main thread will carry on executing, reach the end of its block, and close the http request. Your detached thread is then left writing to a non-existent `out` stream.

**UPDATE in response to your EDIT:** POST is not supported in SSE. Data can only be passed to an SSE process by using GET data or cookies.

Comment: I deleted the loop and the thread just to make sure that I get the data. It works (see above), but the connections is not kept alive.

Comment: You need the infinite loop: as soon as your process ends the SSE connection will close.